# Implementing a Doubly Linked List with Bubble Sort

Tags: java, linked-list, bubble-sort

I'm implementing a Dobly Linked List using the following:  **import java.util.LinkedList;** with a Bubble Sort for an assignment.  After doing research on sorting and Linked List, I learned that I should not use the index to bubble sort a linked list because indeces don't exist in Linked List, or it is too much trouble to implement successfully.

So, having read that, I wrote the following code, but I'm still not sure if I am in the right path.

I need some help in the understanding of the logic behind the bubble sort implementation with a dobly linked list.

Also, I need some reassurance as to whether I am going in the right path efficiently, or if I am utterly wrong in my attempts at this coding exercise.

```
 //This for loop sorts the smaller part of the bubble sort.
for(int i = 0; i < cars.size() - 1; i++)
    {        //This part creates the second "larger" part of the bubble sort.
        for(int j = i + 1; j < cars.size(); j++)
        {


//Did I do this part correctly?  This is where the swap and sort of the bubble sort        takes //place.
//Obviously, I am using the comparable interface, since I am using the compareTo method.
//

//with the bubblesort, all elements must be greater than zero because for the bubble          //sort, 0 is the smallest element in a set of integers.


            if(cars.get(i).getName().compareTo(cars.get(j).getName()) > 0)
            {
                CarName cari = cars.get(i);
                CarName CarNamej = cars.get(j);
                cars.remove(i);
                cars.add(i, carj);
                cars.remove(j);
                cars.add(j, cari);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I use this to output this method in the main method to output the sorted results:

```
bubbleSort(cars);
```

Am I correct, or did I do something completely wrong in all of my code?

Comment: I think you should first complete the problem by one way and then ask if there is some problem with that

Comment: That's the problem, I am sorting a set of data in integer format, so wouldn't it be better if I used the bubbleSort the way I have coded it?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are on the right path. You need to eliminate the use of indexes completely and instead use node references. First develop code to remove an element from the list given just the reference to the element. Then develop code to insert an element into the list just before an element already in the list, given only references to the two elements. You can then build the sorting algorithm on top of these two methods.

For instance, here's how one might remove an element:

```
void remove(Element element) {
    element.previous().setNext(element.next());
    element.next().setPrevious(element.previous());
}
```

You should understand how a doubly linked list works enough to see why this code should work for an element in the middle of the list. Depending on how you represent the list, you might need to test for end conditions (`element.previous()` and/or `element.next()` being `null`).

Comment: From what I understood from the material I consulted, LinkedList allow you the chance to not be concerned with the indeces of the information you are going to sort.  Hence, you can be concerned only with the information itself.  Isn't swapping the nodes inefficient if you are not using an Array to conduct the bubble sort?

Comment: @edxyz - Perhaps I misunderstood. I was under the impression that you were implementing your own doubly linked list structure. If you are using `java.util.LinkedList`, then your current approach is good. However, I would suggest using `set` instead of `remove` followed by `add`.

Comment: Yes. I am using import java.util.LinkedList;  But just needed some clarification as to the logic involved in my coding to make sure I was on the right track.  I've added more comments and explanations to the various portions of logic in the code above.  Thank you.

Comment: @edxyz - It mostly seems correct. You seem to have a typo where you've named the variable `CarNamej` instead of `carj`. ALso, like I said, I'd suggest using `cars.set(i, carj);` instead of `cars.remove(i);` followed by `cars.add(i, carj);`, and similarly for position `j`.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the way Bubble Sort works on a regular Array. A simple Bubble Sort implementation looks likes this:

```
   for (int i = array.Length; i > 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i-1; j++)
            {
                if (array[j] > array[j+1])
                {
                    int tmp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1]=tmp;
                }
                DisplayElements(array);
            }
        }
```

The difference is that instead of using a temp int you'll have to store the reference to the next and previous Node in your List

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of what a bubble sort looks like using an array. Thank you refreshing me.  I'll keep this in mind and understand my code further.

Comment: The only thing to remember is the difference in the data structure you're working with. Arrays are sequential while a Linked List is by references in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

In an array or vector you access stored variables via the index, i.e. position in the list of items.

In a linked list, you get to a specific item by hopping from one item to the next.

Since you are using `get(i)` in your code, you are obviously using an array or a vector as you are indexing by a position in the list. So, nope... unfortunately you are on an entirely wrong track...

once you are getting closer, your code will look more like:

```
boolean changed = true;
while (changed) {  // keep going until we didn't make any more changes (not
                   // strictly the best condition for bubble sort, but it'll do)

    a = first;                  // grab first element
    b = a.next;                 // grab next element
    changed = false;
    while (b!=last) {           // run through all elements
        if (a.value>b.value) {  // compare the two elements; swap if out of order
            a.prev.next = b;    // update element before a to be followed by b
            b.next.prev = a;    // update element after b to be preceeded by a
            a.prev = b;         // b is now before a
            b.next = a;         // and a is after b
            changed = true;     // we made a change, so we're not done
        } else {
            a = b;              // if we didn't swap them, move to next pair
        }
        b = a.next;             // second half of next pair is next after a
    }
}
```

This is just to give you a rough idea. It's by no means complete or bug free. For example, you would need to update `first` instead of `a.prev` in the line `a.prev.next = b` if a you were in the very beginning of the list, etc. ... But hey... you don't want to have someone else do your homework for you anyways, right? ;)

Basically, in a doubly linked list each element knows how to get to the next element (a.next) and the previous element (a.prev). Bubble sort is a good candidate for sorting this kind of linked list as it only ever compares neighboring elements. Otherwise, quick-sort or merge-sort or a combination thereof could be much faster, but they do need indexed access to elements, which a linked list usually doesn't provide.

Hope this helps.

BTW: Youtube has a whole bunch of cool videos explaining all sorts of these things nicely.

One more serious one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P00xJgWzz2c

And a more unusual one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyZQPjUT5B4 (the one of these for quick-sort has much better music :)

Comment: Thanks for the videos.  I'll definitely watch them.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you convert the linked list in an array, sort the array and then copy contents back to linked list.

Comment: Java API has inbuilt methods to convert a list into array and vice versa. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#toArray(T[])